# Have a string field which has "(UTC-03:00) - Santiago" need to extract time -03:00 and convert to seconds in BigQuery

Tags: function, time, google-bigquery

I have values like below , in a string field "**timezone_name**"

(UTC-03:00) - Santiago
(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
(UTC)

I can extract values -03:00, -04:00, +05:30 using below code:

CASE  WHEN STRPOS(timezone_name,"+")=5 THEN SUBSTR(timezone_name,5,6)
      WHEN STRPOS(timezone_name,"-")=5 THEN SUBSTR(timezone_name,5,6)
      ELSE '0'

Any direct way converting this time values to seconds,believe I can multiply this hours by 86400 will give me seconds but want to know any function in Big Query which i can use directly in case statement.

Expected output is to convert that time value to Seconds , as an e.g. 05:30 should be converted to 19800, -04:00 should be converted to -14400

Comment: what is `timezone_name` and what is `section_timezone_display_name`? also provide expected output for shown input data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT timezone_name, 
  CASE REGEXP_EXTRACT(timezone_name, r'UTC([+-])') 
    WHEN '-' THEN -1
    ELSE 1 
  END * TIME_DIFF(
    CAST(CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(timezone_name, r'UTC[+-]([:0-9]*)'), ':00') AS TIME), 
    '00:00:00', 
    SECOND
  ) AS offset_in_seconds
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row timezone_name                                       offset_in_seconds    
1   (UTC-03:00) - Santiago                              -10800   
2   (UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)                  -14400   
3   (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi     19800
```